# Does the Dropbox app disintegrate photos the same way iCloud does?

Tags: image-quality

On iOS devices, having “ iCloud photos” and “optimize storage” turned on causes photos on the device to be replaced with low quality versions. Is this the same situation with the Dropbox app?

Comment: This is yet another in a series of "will *x* reduce my picture quality?" Why don't you just store them on a hard drive, then **you're** in charge of what happens to them?

Comment: @Tetsujin to transfer images from a mobile device to a hard drive (automatically) one needs to jump through quite some hoops. Dropbox simplifies those steps tremendously. I think it's a valid question, but could perhaps be broadened to something like "what iOS sync app does not reduce the quality of photos stored on the device?"

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke - Launch Image Capture, set destination, hit Go. Done. This is the 8th question along similar lines. There is a distinct lack of learning going on here.

Comment: `Launch Image Capture` what if one is on Windows? Linux? And this requires that the user remembers to do this periodically. Also, if you feel this is a duplicate, can we not mark it as such?
`There is a distinct lack of learning going on here`, by whom? I don't think we can treat all the users with this question as a single entity that does not learn.

Comment: You could just turn off optimize storage. It’s not like you lose access to the full resolution images in any case.

Comment: I am with Tetsujin.  I want full control of my images. ( *Clouds are transient, who chose that name?* )  It sounds like icloud is storing your photo files  "in the cloud"  yet only placing a low quality thumbnail/version on your device, correct?  Have you **asked dropbox** how they handle that process ? Is dropbox the best platform for photos on your phone?  If you want the full size on your phone then why send them off your phone?

Comment: DropBox is a **file** storage service, vice a picture service. They do not alter your files. Now they do generate a hash and if the hash is a duplicate of a file *or picture* then rather than store the same thing twice, they just link to the single version they already have, but this is utterly transparent to the user.

Answer (score 2):

No. Dropbox uploaded JPEGS are bitwise identical to the ones on the phone. I do not know what it does with HEIF images.

In any case, Dropbox won't change the images on the device itself. Also, DB doesn't even have an “optimize storage” option.